# do we have ellipse detection in OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, ellipse, canny-operator

I am detecting the wheels in the image. I am trying to fit ellipses to the wheels and find the contact point between ellipses and ground.

Here is the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx19g.jpg)

When it is a circle, this would be pretty easy, and I understand how to fit a circle.
But when it comes to ellipses, I can't get anything that works accurately. I read the image

```
image=cv2.imread("image.jpg")
gray=cv2.GaussianBlur(image,(7,7),0)
cv2.imshow('GaussianBlur',gray)

#Canny
edged=cv2.Canny(gray,50,50)
edged=cv2.dilate(edged,None,iterations=1)
edged=cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)
cv2.imshow('edged',edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

**Edited: what is really important for me is to find one point at the bottom of the eclipse where it touches the ground.**

Comment: a possible solution might be: find the tyres/ellipses (may be hough transform work for this), then find the center of ellipse and draw a vertical line that passes through the center. The point where vertical line touches the ellipse at bottom will be the point of contact to the ground. Goodluck

Comment: I tried Hough transform many times, unfortunately, it does not work. If it works for you, pls let me know

Comment: Unfortunately opencv does not have hough transform for ellipse. I can think of two solutions: 1. Try skimage (example: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html); 2. Use opencv EllipseModel to fit ellipse on your each sub image.